# How to define actuators in URDF exporter?

Tags: ros, sw-urdf-exporter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have an assembly that looks like this: [image: AUV]

Now this doesn't have joints but does have 6 actuators. I have to use sw2urdf exporter to use the mesh in Gazebo Sim so that I can define the thrusters as actuators in the simulator. I am not able to understand what are joints and what are links in this assembly. Please help me out, a little hint would be sufficient.

Thanks for making this tool. Really appreciate it.

Kshitij Goel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252051/how-to-define-actuators-in-urdf-exporter?/) by [kshitijgoel007](https://answers.ros.org/users/29057/kshitijgoel007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-15**:
Your image is not showing. Please attach it directly to your question. I've given you enough karma to do that.

**Comment by [kshitijgoel007](https://answers.ros.org/users/29057/kshitijgoel007/) on 2017-01-15**:
Just added it. Thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are talking about the `actuator` elements inside [transmission](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/Transmission)s, then you can't add those using the sw2urdf plugin.

You'll have to do that manually, by editing the urdf after exporting it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kshitijgoel007](https://answers.ros.org/users/29057/kshitijgoel007/) on 2017-01-16**:
Thanks for your answer. I have noted this. Can you please have a look again at the question? I have added the image now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-16**:
I'm not sure I would change my answer. The exporter derives joint locations by looking at SW mates, which I don't think you have. Also: joints probably don't make much sense here. If you're just after having a mesh for Gazebo then you can just export without any joints defined.